# javax bean validation not resolving message code

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am using javax bean validation in a spring mvc project.
Here is my sample code.

User.java :-

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{error.user.username.empty}")
private String userName;
```

UserController.java :-

```
public String handleSubmission(@ModelAttribute("user")@Valid User user, BindingResult errors) {
        ....
    }
```

messages_en.properties :-

```
error.user.username.empty=Username can not be empty
NotEmpty.user.userName=Username can not be empty
```

Whenever 'userName' field is empty the validation fails as expected but application throws an exception,

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'NotEmpty' for locale 'en_US'.
```

In the log i can see,

```
Field error in object 'user' on field 'userName': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.user.userName,NotEmpty.userName,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.userName,userName]; arguments []; default message [userName]]; default message [Username cannot be empty]
```

The message key used in the validation annotation is 'error.user.username.empty' and that key is defined in messages_en.properties but application only looks 
for key 'NotEmpty'. Even adding key 'NotEmpty.user.userName' doesn't help. 
Exception goes away only if i add 'NotEmpty' key to properties file, e.g.

```
NotEmpty=Username can not be empty
```

The MessageSource configuration is as follows,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

The JSP code to display error messages is,

user.jsp :-

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="user">
   <ul>
       <li> <span class="error">Please fix all errors and try again.</span></li>    
      <c:forEach var="error" items="${errors.allErrors}">
       <li> <span class="error"><spring:message code="${error.code}"/></span></li>
      </c:forEach>
   </ul>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

**Update:-**

No luck even with - `<form:errors path="userName"/>.`

I just displayed error codes and default error messages in the JSP with following code,

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="user">
            <c:forEach var="error" items="${errors.allErrors}">
                <span class="error">${error.code} - ${error.defaultMessage}</span>
            </c:forEach>
    </spring:hasBindErrors>
```

The output is,

```
NotEmpty - Username cannot be empty
```

That means defaultMessage 'Username cannot be empty' is getting read properly from ValidationMessages.properties file. Because that is the message defined there. But error code is still 'NotEmpty'. 
So in summary,

1. If i try to display messages by iterating over all errors as shown in JSP code above i get an exception.
2. If i use `<form:errors path="*" />` all error messages are displayed for bean 'user' EXCEPT javax bean validation messages.
3. Using `<form:errors path="userName" />` displays nothing.

Comment: Which properties file? Add your configuration and jsp.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum. Updated question with configuration and jsp code. I have defined messages in messages_en.properties file.

Comment: use `<form:errors />` instead of what you have now. The `${error.code}` will only resolve a single code. Either use `${error}` or just use the `<form:errors  path="users" />` tag instead of what you have now.

Comment: I tried your approach. In that case what happens is no exception is thrown and no javax.validation error messages are displayed.
But apart from javax bean validation i am manually doing some other validations. Those messages are getting displayed in JSP. 
For example,
- if (Utils.isDuplicateUserName(user)) {
 errors.rejectValue("username", "error.username.taken");
} -
In jsp i have now <form:errors path="user"/>. javax bean validations are not getting displayed even though in the debug mode i can see 
there are javax bean validation errors

Comment: When you rejecting things yourself you only have a single code, when you use spring you have multiple codes. Now calling `getCode` will only return one of those codes. The path should be the same as you use in your `<form:input />` so it shouldn't be user but `userName`.

Comment: Hello Deinum, i just added an update to my question in response to your latest comment. Thanks

Comment: Using `<form:errors />` requires that you also use `<form:form />` do you actually use that (I doubt as you were using the old style `<spring:bind />` tags.

Comment: Yes of course. I am using the <form:form> tag and <form:errors /> is within  <form:form> tag

Comment: Your first option fails because your iteration is wrong (as I explained). Nonetheless it should just work with the errors tag, so you must be doing something strange that breaks that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `ValidationMessages.properties` in your classpath and add your validation error messages there.

**Update** Customize your `Validator` to use the registered `MessageSource`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());

        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. I missed to mention it but i tried that approach as well. I have a file named ValidationMessages.properties in 'src/main/resources' folder alongside messages_en.properties file with required message codes defined. But unfortunately it doesn't work with same exception as earlier

Comment: Tried your suggestion. But it didn't resolve the issue :-(